# consider the following subsets of complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices

$$\Omega_1=\left\{c\in\Bbb C:\begin{bmatrix}1&c\\\bar c&1\\ \end{bmatrix}\text{ is non-negative definite } \right\} $$

$$\Omega_2= \left\{c\in\Bbb C:
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & c & c \\
        \bar c & 1 & c \\
        \bar c & \bar c & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \text{ is non-negative definite } \right\}$$

Let $$\bar D=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|\le1\}$$
Then 1) $\Omega_1=\bar D,\Omega_2=\bar D$

2). $\Omega_1\neq\bar D, \Omega_2=\bar D$

3). $\Omega_1=\bar D, \Omega_2\neq\bar D$

4). $\Omega_1\neq\bar D, \Omega_2\neq\bar D$

How to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: First, recall the definition of a non-negative definite matrix. What conditions does this put on $c$ in each case?

Comment: If these were real numbers, the first thing I would think of is that if the variance of each of two or three random variables is $1$, then the covariance is the correlation, and the correlation is always in $[-1,1]$, so $-1\le c\le 1$.  Here one relies on the fact that the set of all matrices of covariances is precisely the set of all non-negative-definite matrices.  My first guess is $|c|\le 1$ for both $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: non negative means positive semi definite i.e. all eigen values are ≥0 and atleast one eigen value 0

Comment: Just as a matter of style, I'd rather write  $\{c\in\mathbb C:|c|\le 1\}$, using $c$ rather than $z$ as in the definitions of the other two sets. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: [Helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)

Comment: @Michel Hardy : if we take $c=-1$ then 3by3 matrix is non singuler with determinant value -4 which contradicting the given condition

Comment: @Chiranjeev : You're right: Now that you mention that, I'm remembering that _some_ exchangeable sequences of random variables cannot be extended to longer exchangeable sequences, and non-extendability can in some cases be seen just by looking at the correlations.  The $1$s on the diagonal are the correlations between a random variable and itself and $c$ is the correlation between distinct ones.  If a pair is $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, each with probability $1/2$ then the $2\times2$ matrix with $c=-1$ is the matrix of correlations between the $x$- and $y$-componens of the pair, and${}\,\ldots\quad{}$

Comment: ${}\ldots\,{}$that cannot be extended to a sequence of length $3$, $(1,0,\text{?})$ or $(0,1,\text{?})$ in which every pair of components has the same distribution.  Hence we rule out $c=-1$ in the $3\times3$ case.

Comment: @Michael Hardy : is there any other way to handle this problem? you are handling this problem by statistics maths, which is unknown for me.

Comment: Suppose the correlation between any two of $n$ distinct random variables is $c$; then if I recall correctly, one must have $c\ge-1/(n-1)$. Supposing all variances are $1$, so that the correlations are the covariances, then we have $\operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = (\operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots) + 2\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2)+\cdots)$ $= n + n(n-1)(-1/(n-1)) = 0$.  If the variance is $0$, then the random variable is constant.  That's when you can't extend it to a longer exchangeable sequence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Chiranjeev : There are of course other ways to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Note that the matrices are Hermitian, so it is enough to check if the eigenvalues $\lambda\geq 0$ are non-negative, or equivalently, 
   $$\mu~:=~1-\lambda~\leq~ 1.$$
2. The [characteristic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Characteristic_polynomial) read
   $$ p_1(\lambda) ~=~\mu^2-|c|^2, $$
   and
   $$  p_2(\lambda) ~=~\mu^3+|c|^2(2{\rm Re}(c) -3\mu), $$
   respectively.
3. Define polar decomposition $c~=~re^{i\theta}~\in~\mathbb{C}$.
4. The roots are 
   $$ \mu~=~\pm |c|,$$
   and
   $$ \mu = 2 r \cos\frac{\theta+2\pi p}{3},\qquad p\in\mathbb{Z},$$
   respectively.
5. Hence,
   $$ \Omega_1~=~\{c\in \mathbb{C} \mid |c|\leq 1\}~=~\bar{D}, $$
   while
   $$   \Omega_2~=~\{re^{i\theta}\in \mathbb{C} \mid \forall p\in \mathbb{Z}:~ 2 r \cos\frac{\theta+2\pi p}{3}\leq 1\}~\neq~\bar{D}. $$
   It is straightforward to check that
   $$  \{c\in \mathbb{C} \mid |c|\leq \frac{1}{2}\}~\subsetneq~\Omega_2~\subsetneq~\bar{D}. $$

Answer (score 3):

The $2\times 2$ matrix has eigenvalues $1 \pm |c|$, so it is positive semidefinite if and only if $|c|\leq 1$.

For the $3\times 3$ matrix, observe that the determinant is $-4$ when $c=-1$, so the matrix is not positive semidefinite in this case.